# Using the ENTRYPOINT tag from Dockerfile with docker-compose

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I have a python project with some code. My `main.py` file provides the right instruction to run all my code. I need to run `python main.py`.

For this project, I have written a `Dockerfile` with an `ENTRYPOINT` tag.
When I build my code with the `docker build` command and then run it, it works well.

Now, I'm trying to use `docker-compose` instead of `docker`.
The problem is that the `ENTRYPOINT` tag (from my Dockerfile) doesn't work into my `docker-compose.yml` file.

Indeed, I need to enter my container and to execute `python main.py`

How can I make my `ENTRYPOINT` understandable for `docker-compose`? Can you help me?

`docker-compose.yml` :

```
version: '2'
services:
  my-service:
    container_name: test
    build:
      context: ..
      dockerfile: ./deploy/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ../config.json:/app/config.json
    environment:
      DOCKER_APP: "True"
```

`Dockerfile` :

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

RUN apt-get update; apt-get install -y git

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY project/* app/

WORKDIR app/

ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "main.py"]
```

Comment: Why do you think you need to start it differently from the compose file? It's already running python3 main.py. You could split it into cmd and entrypoint to make it easier to run other things, but you don't seem to actually want to.

Comment: My code doesn't work when I use docker-compose.yml (which is using my Dockerfile), I want it to work.
I tried CMD and ENTRYPOINT. Both didn't work and it didn't provide logs.

Comment: What exactly does *"doesn't work"* mean? What outputs and error messages do you see? Why do you think this will fix it? And of course you want it to work.

Comment: In addition to everything @jonrsharpe is asking: when you say you can `docker run` it successfully without Compose, what command are you running, and how does it behave differently?

Comment: I run `docker run --mount  type=bind,source=/path/to/project/config.json,target=/app/config.json crypto-recover` to run my container
I also use `docker build -f deploy/Dockerfile .` to build it

And also `docker-compose up` for docker-compose

Comment: The difference is :
 - when I use the Dockerfile + build + run, my script starts running 
 - when I use docker-compose it doesn't